# How to apply same styles to 2 different classes in 2 different breakpoints?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I've a chunk of (S)CSS that I need to apply to 2 different elements in 2 different breakpoints to avoid redundancy, is that possible? (I'm using Bootstrap 4.6).
E.g.: (simplified)

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="content">Something</div>
</div>

<div class="two">
    <div class="content">Something</div>
</div>
```

```
.one {
  @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
    thead {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

Now I need the same styles that apply to .one in breakpoint md also to apply to .two in breakpoint lg.

Comment: Since you are using SCSS, could you make it a @mixin? Since you have two breakpoints, native CSS will have to separate those, so using SCSS will be your best bet to organize the code on your end.

Comment: A mixin would probably reduce maintenance redundancy in the SCSS but would still end up with redundant compiled CSS, right? If there's no other way so be it, I was hoping there's some sneaky CSS selector syntax that I don't know to avoid both redundancies...

Comment: As I mentioned, you can't combine different breakpoints in native CSS. If one is applied with a mid-width of 500px and the other a min-width of 1000px, then those have to be written separately since you can't nest media queries in native CSS.

Comment: I had a look at mixins but they are probably not exactly what I'm looking for since they can only contain properties but I have a whole set of classes instead. Can that be done? Basically in SCSS I need to end up with something like this:
Set of classes: `thead{}; tbody{}; tfooter{};`
`.one{  @include media-breakpoint-down(md) { SET OF CLASSES HERE } }`
`.two{  @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) { SET OF CLASSES HERE } }`

Comment: Update - actually it does work, I had a typo in my SCSS which lead to wrong compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a SCSS mixin that I included the other classes. Though I could only find mixins containing properties (e.g. color: red;) in the SASS/SCSS documentation, it does also work when containing whole CSS classes.

```
@mixin table-custom {
    thead   {...}
    tbody   {...}
    tfooter {...}
}

.one {
    @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
        @include table-custom;
    }
}

.two {
    @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
        @include table-custom;
    }
}
```